# why could not pull github code in terminal

Tags: git

Now I could access github.com from Google Chrome broswer, but I could not pull code in terminal:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open% git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/cruise-open.git/': Connection timed out after 300016 milliseconds
```

when I am ping github.com, output like this:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open% ping github.com
PING github.com (13.250.177.223) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ec2-13-250-177-223.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com (13.250.177.223): icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=125 ms
64 bytes from ec2-13-250-177-223.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com (13.250.177.223): icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=124 ms
64 bytes from ec2-13-250-177-223.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com (13.250.177.223): icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=118 ms
64 bytes from ec2-13-250-177-223.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com (13.250.177.223): icmp_seq=4 ttl=45 time=123 ms
64 bytes from ec2-13-250-177-223.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com (13.250.177.223): icmp_seq=5 ttl=45 time=119 ms
64 bytes from ec2-13-250-177-223.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com (13.250.177.223): icmp_seq=6 ttl=45 time=124 ms
64 bytes from ec2-13-250-177-223.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com (13.250.177.223): icmp_seq=7 ttl=45 time=124 ms
```

what should I do to make pull github code work? I have already clone the repo before. Yes, my broswer using a proxy. But the terminal using proxy also did not work. I am switch the proxy like this in terminal:

```
alias proxy="export all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7890"
```

Comment: How did you clone the repository? Did you change anything after cloning? Does your browser use a proxy for HTTPS? Please [edit] your question to answer.

Answer (score 0):

add proxy:

```
git config --global --add remote.origin.proxy "127.0.0.1:7890"
```

works for me.